# How can I make some items in a JComboBox unselectable?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How can I make some of my JComboBox Items unselectable? I tried this:

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
    int index. boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    Component comp = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
        isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    if (not selectable conditions) {
        comp.setEnabled(false);
        comp.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        comp.setEnabled(true);
        comp.setFocusable(true);
    }

    return comp;
}
```

The items become gray, but are still selectable by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the selected item to the last selected item when an 'unselectable' item is selected.  That means you need to store the 'last selected item' in a field.

Comment: That might have a bad effect if someone was trying to use the keyboard to go down a list of items. Going down to the unselectable one would perpetually bounce back to the previous.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would be tempted to do this would be to only show the user(s) the valid items, anything invalid make invisible. I hope this helps.